# Android maven dependency for API level 15

Tags: android, maven

Is it possible to add dependency in my Android project with Maven support for API level 15 ?

I have followed definition:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
    <artifactId>android</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

where `4.0.1.2` is API level 14. next available is `4.1.1.4` which is API level 16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you really need to downgrade to a previous api version via a dependency. Can't you just change the platform level in the **plugin config**?

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <sdk>
                    <platform>15</platform>
                </sdk>
                <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

And in **project.properties:**

```
target=android-15
```

Answer (score 1):

API level 15 (Android 4.0.3, 4.0.4) is not yet available in the [Maven central repository](http://search.maven.org/#browse%7C-697723448).

You can download the android.jar via SDK Manager then manually install it into your local maven repository:

```
mvn install:install-file \
  -DgroupId=com.google.android \
  -DartifactId=android \
  -Dpackaging=jar \
  -Dversion= 4.0.3 \
  -Dfile=/android-sdk-home/platforms/android-15/android.jar
```

Then start using it in your project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
    <artifactId>android</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.3</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Note that you can use whatever name you want for groupId, artifactId and version when install the jar file, for instance, the convention used by [maven-android-sdk-deployer](https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer) is:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>android</groupId>
  <artifactId>android</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.3_r3</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```